# PHP MySQL daily select

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a query that select 2 random results from my database everyday. I cannot make it select once everyday, so here is my query right now:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() limit 2
```

My table does only have a id and a name field in it.

So, how I can make the website only select this once a day?

Comment: The first time you run the query, write the data to a file on disk. Each time you run the code after that, check stats on the file and see if it is older then midnight last night. If it's older, request the data, write the file over. If it's not older, read the data from the file and display it. Alternatives: use a caching server, do it with a cron job, or store the data in another database table.

Comment: If I was doing this, I would have a separate table with a single row containing the last timestamp from when you selected the random rows. Update the timestamp in the row every time you do it, and only select the rows if it's a new day. This way, you don't need to write to a file.

Comment: Don't `ORDER BY rand()`, especially if you don't have a `WHERE` clause to filter the result set. It is painfully slow for tables having thousands of rows. Make the `ID` column auto-incremented, get its maximum value, generate how many random numbers you need in PHP (between 1 and the max) then get the corresponding rows from the database (in a single query using `ID IN (...)`) or in individual queries (if you have holes in the `ID` column).

Comment: I went with mbomb007's suggestion, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to seed the random number generate with the date, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY rand(year(now()) * 1000 + month(now()) * 100 + day(now()))
limit 2;
```